# Access function in other scope, while having acces to a sibling

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to change a external library (ember-data). But i can't access the scope of the function i want to change.

I made a js fiddle with a explanation and a very simplified usecase:
http://jsfiddle.net/yr5Lmzyk/3/

```
// =========== External libary (cannot be changed)---------------------------
var ex = {};
(function (__exp__){
    ob = {
        prefix: 'object-prefix',
        say: function(word){
             return this.prefix + "|" + abcd(word);   
        }
    };

    function abcd(a){
     return a + "|function-postfix";   
    }
__exp__.ob = ob;
}(ex));

var ob = ex.ob;

// ================= Available/ ajustable code ---------------------
// i want to change the working of the abcd function.
// in the real case abcd is used in many functions of ob, but i only want to change that function.
$("#content").html(ob.say("call-parameter"));
```

The upper part is the "external" lib, i can't change.
The lower part is my code, where i've got access to. When i run the say method on the ob object, it uses the function abcd. I want to change the working of this function.

How can i access this scope, to change the abcd function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abcd` funntion its *private* you cannot change it, you can change the `say` function, but there is no way you can access things that have not been exposed

Comment: I thought maybe can it be changed by altering the prototype of say or by adding an extra function to ob, in that scope, that will change the prototype of abcd.

Comment: no you can't touch `abcd` it lives in memory, its not inside an object or anything, there is no way to access it. you can do what you want with `say` or `prefix` because they are exposed.